# How to extract specific value from XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, automation

I need to extract values of elements: `price` and `publisher`,  given the `title` of the book from this XML.

```xml
<book>
    <title>Burning Tower</title>
    <author>Larry Niven</author>
    <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
    <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
    <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
    <price>5.99</price>
</book>
```

How this can be done?

I need to extract attribute name when field name is given. Suppose if I have field name Testing, then I need to extract attribute value for name corresponding to that field.

```
<RequirementFieldList>
  <field name="SN_Name">Testing</field>
  <field name="Email1">Test1_User</field>
  <field name="Email2">na</field>
  <field name="Email3">na</field>
  <field name="Email4">na</field>
</RequirementFieldList>
```

Comment: price is inside title or book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the XPath: `book[title='foo']/price` will give you the price values of all books with the title "`foo`". To get the publisher you can just use: `book[title='foo']/publisher`.

This provides a similar example to yours:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

Comment: Thank You  so much. Please provide answer of 2nd question which I have added in this question too.

Comment: @AnchalSarraf For your second question, simply
`RequirementFieldList/field[text()="Testing"]/@name`